# Is there a way to do or simulate busy/wait style input in browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, browser

I want to convert some command line style programs into JavaScript for use in a browser.  I'm planning on using xterm.js to orchestrate the terminal aspect of the project, but I'm at a loss for how to convert these to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript in the browser.  These programs use busy/wait style input.. like this:

```
print ("what is your name")
name = input() // waits until user enters data
print ("hello ", name)
print ("how old are you")
age = input()  // waits until user enters data
...
```

I know I can redesign the whole program to be asynchronous, but I want to avoid that since it would be a pretty substantial amount of work.  Is anyone aware of any techniques that can achieve this without a huge redesign?

Comment: prompt() ??????

Comment: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/4.14.1/typings/xterm.d.ts#L688

Comment: Are you expecting the user to work with the Javascript console in the browser?  If you expect to deliver this as a normal web page, then you have to redesign this to display an HTML form, and have a web app on your server to handle the responses from the user.

Comment: @epascarello prompt is close to what I'm looking for but it's a dialog.  I'd like something to take input through the xterm widget on the page.  the onKey and onData events are asynchronous--I can't easily insert it into the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to imitate a console, you can look at example on main page of [Xterm.js website](https://xtermjs.org/) ([source code](https://xtermjs.org/js/demo.js)).

You need to handle `onData()` event.

Comment: yea, that's the point.  handling the onData() event is asynchronous.  In the sample code above, how do you resume after the input statement?  You would have to have some sort of switch/case for all inputs in your application (just like the xterm sample code)--which is basically redesigning the entire application. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You could replace all blocking read/writes of the original app with async/await shims, that simulate the blocking nature in the promise executor.